# ASP.NET Web Api in Views

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I want to create a login page via webapi with this situations .

i dont want  to use token and.. but the views should be secure (not direct called in URL).

If the user is Admin load view_x.

If the user is Employee load view_y.

If the user is Student load view_z.

please give me suggestion

Comment: This is not a tutorial site. Google will be your best friend in these times. When you begin to write some code and have a specific question regarding `code`, that's where _we're_ here to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you have a front end website which leverages this web API as you are talking about loading of views. Firstly you might want to define roles in your back-end of your web API for various types of users. For e.g. every user will belong to exactly one of the defined roles in your DB like Student, Admin, Employee etc. The action method which is called when your website gets launched will call your web API to validate the authenticity of the user who is trying to login. After the login is successfull it should also fetch the role information of the logged in user from the web API. When you have role information with you then simply use a switch clause as shown below to redirect to appropriate view:

```
public ActionResult Login()
        {
            //call web api to validate the user credentials
            var role = <call the web api to get the role of the user>;
            switch (role)
            {
                case "Admin" :
                    return View("Admin");
                case "Student" :
                    return View("Student");
                case "Employee" :
                    return View("Employee");
                case "Others" :
                    return View("Others");
            }
        }
```

Hope this helps!