# ajax calls the mvc controller

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

why this code does not work?.I receive "ok" but i can not see the view1 (view1 not loaded).I want to manage the views by prop1 .If the value of prop1="1" load view1

Hier is my controller

```
[System.Web.Mvc.Route("Home/SubmitMyData/")]
        [System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
        public ActionResult SubmitMyData([FromBody]MyParamModel mydata)
        {


            if (mydata.Prop1.Equals("1"))
                return View("veiw1");
            else
                        return View("view2");


        }

        public class MyParamModel // #4
        {
            public string Prop1 { get; set; }
            public string Prop2 { get; set; }
        }
```

and it is my ajax call

```
   $('#Buttonv').click(function () {

        var myData = {Prop1: "1", Prop2: ""}; // #1
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            data: myData, // #2
            url: '/Home/SubmitMyData',          
        })
           .success(function (data) {
               var output = "ok";

               $('#lblmessage').html(output);

           })
        .error(function (xhr, ajaxoption, thrownError) {
            $('#lblmessage').html("moshkelo" + xhr + "ajaxoption= " + ajaxoption + " throwerror=" + thrownError);
        });
        //return false;
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are returning a View from your Controller, you'll need to ensure that you are actually using the HTML content within the `success` callback of your POST :

```
.success(function (data) {
     // data will contain your content
     $('#lblmessage').html(data);
 })
```

You were previous using `output`, which didn't seem to be defined anywhere within your script.

Additionally, you may want to check the name of the view that you are returning as `return View("veiw1");` seems like a typo that should be `return View("View1");`.

Comment: 1:The data is not important. i just want to call  " public ActionResult SubmitMyData" and return the "veiw1".      2: the name veiw1 is true. 3:output is not also important for me. its just a message

Comment: 1. Assuming your `url` is being resolved properly, that's fine it should be calling that properly. 2. I was just making sure that wasn't a typo. 3. You mention that the output is not important yet you want to be returning a view. The parameter that is output in your `success` function (i.e. `data` in the above example) will contain all of the HTML that your View would render, so if you wanted to display it, you would use something like `$(element).html(data);`.

Comment: Have you tried placing a breakpoint in your Controller Action to ensure that your model is being populated correctly?

Comment: thank you ,it works. if you have time please guide me . its the question . but i do not call my web api. i want to load new pages(views). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36462587/asp-net-web-api-in-views

Answer (score 0):

In your javascript, you are ignoring the HTML returned by the server.  Try changing it to...

```
       .success(function (data) {
           $('#lblmessage').html(data);
       })
```

Per the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), the first parameter to the `success` method is the data returned by the server.

Comment: but the data is not important for me. i just want to call  "public ActionResult SubmitMyData([FromBody]MyParamModel mydata) " in my controller.